# Command to open new R Session from R source file

Tags: r, memory, command

I run some calculations over several hours with R. After a while my memory is full of junk. The gc() and rm() command don't solve the problem. What I did is that I shut down my R session and opend a new one. This solves the memory problem. Now I want to automate this process. Is there a command to open a second R session or RGui form an existing session. Then I want to set the wd in this second session, run some code there and close it after some time. How can I do this? Alternatively, is there another way to get rid of the junk in my memory.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about this. Can you be more specific in your problem description?

Comment: my problem is that I run out of memory. that's why I want to "reboot" R. but it's tiring to do it manually, so I want to automatize this process.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give `Rscript` a try, see `Rscript --help` from command line. Break down your big script into smaller parts and run them in succession using the same workspace with `Rscript --restore --save yourscript.r`. A new session of R will be opened for each script which may help you to keep memory use under control.